# Is it possible to use the `auto` keyword as a return type in a function pointer declaration with initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, function-pointers, auto

The following code [compiles successfully both with *clang++ 3.8.0* and *g++ 7.2.0*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/877293523244614b) (the compilation flags are `-std=c++14 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`):

```
#include <iostream>


int foo_int(int)
{
    std::cout << "int foo(int)" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void foo_void(int)
{
    std::cout << "void foo(int)" << std::endl;
}

auto foo_auto_int(int)
{
    std::cout << "auto foo(int), auto == int" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

auto foo_auto_void(int)
{
    std::cout << "auto foo(int), auto == void" << std::endl;

    return void();
}


int main()
{
    auto (*fi)(int) = foo_int;
    auto (*fv)(int) = foo_void;
    auto (*fai)(int) = foo_auto_int;
    auto (*fav)(int) = foo_auto_void;

    (void)fi(0);
    fv(0);
    (void)fai(0);
    fav(0);
}
```

Is it a valid C++ code?

Note that the `decltype(auto)` is [rejected both by *clang++* and *g++* in the same situation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ad435aa8653f0e5).

Comment: Why don't you just write `auto p = foo_int;`...?

Comment: @PasserBy Of course, I can. I simply want to know such construction is valid or not valid.

Comment: `decltype(auto)` has to appear by itself in the declaration. Its deduction is slightly different, so whatever happens with it is not material to what happens with `auto` in the declaration.

Comment: @StoryTeller I simply want to try some other variants with this strange construction. `auto` is also rejected when it is placed in function parameters fields (something like `void (*f)(auto) = ...` doesn't compile, too). Only `auto` as a return type compiles successfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compilers are behaving correctly.

From [[dcl.spec.auto]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.auto)

> The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` type-specifiers are used to designate a placeholder type that will be replaced later by deduction from an *initializer*.
>
> [...]
>
> `auto` or `decltype(auto)` shall appear as one of the *decl-specifiers* in the *decl-specifier-seq* and the *decl-specifier-seq* shall be followed by one or more *declarators*, each of which shall be followed by a non-empty *initializer*.

Which is saying `auto` and `decltype(auto)` can only be written with the specifiers you write in the front of a declaration (`static`, `virtual` etc), with their types deduced from the immediately following *declarators* with *initializers*.

### The case of `auto`

The *declarator* in the case of `auto (*fi)(int) = foo_int;` is `(*fi)(int)` which is of the form

```
( ptr-operator declarator-id ) ( parameter-declaration-clause )
```

Hence `auto (*fi)(int) = foo_int;` is valid, provided the [deduction succeeds](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-4), which it does. Likewise for the other few.

### The case of `decltype(auto)`

From [[dcl.spec.auto.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-5), given a type `T` containing a placeholder type

> If the placeholder is the `decltype(auto)` *type-specifier*, `T` shall be the placeholder alone.

Which means adding anything else is illegal

```
int i;
decltype(auto)* p = &i;  // error, declared type is not plain decltype(auto)
```

Hence `decltype(auto) (*fi)(int) = foo_int;` is illegal.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. So it is simply a strange special case of the general rule, isn't it?

Comment: @Constructor Yeah, the most common use case is where the declarator is only a declarator-id, `auto i = 42;`

Comment: @Constructor: No. Why would you call it "special"? Usages like `auto &r`, or `auto &&r` or `auto *p` are perfectly mainstream. And these examples are not in any way conceptually different from yours: the `&` and the `*` are not parts of *desc-specifier-seq* either. They are parts of individual declarators, just like your `(int)`. Your example might be from "rarely used" category, but the underlying formal structure is not special at all.

Comment: @AnT Yes, I understand. "Special" was not a good word for this situation. "Rarely used" is more appropriate.